# How create new dataframe that show me only scheduled matches ended last 0-0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

how create new dataframe that show me only scheduled matches ended last 0-0

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    import time
    url = ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Serie-A')
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    df2 = df[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa','Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
    zero_df = df2.loc[(df2['Punteggio'] == '0–0')]
    casa_next = zero_df.Casa
    ospiti_next = zero_df.Ospiti
    data_next = zero_df.Data
```

Comment: Hi Emanuele, welcome to Stack Overflow. A hint about code blocks, use three backticks (`) rather than apostrophes (') for formatting code.

Comment: I appears you've already do it. What is wrong with what you doing?

Comment: I want a dataframe that show me only next matches with the last results 0-0

Comment: Isn't `zero_df` what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are after as your `zero_df` has all the games that show '0-0' result. If you want the last one of them, you can do

```
zero_df.sort_values('Data').head(1)
```

which produces

```
Sett.       Data        Casa        Punteggio   Ospiti
156 15.0    03-01-2021  Fiorentina  0–0         Bologna
```

or if you want the last 3, say, you can do `...head(3)`.

Comment: oh nope... I want a dataframe from 'df2 = df[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa','Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]' that show me the next squads from the last results are 0-0

Comment: @EmanueleNegri it would be very useful if you added the expected output to your question then

Comment: I’ll expected all the next matches where the last results were 0-0

Comment: is that not what you have in `zero_df` anyway?

Comment: @EmanueleNegri as far as I can tell, there are no other fixtures scheduled, in your data for teams that had 0-0 score. If you want help please do provide expected output based on the input data you provided